# How to remove the Windows PATH from a Sublime Text 3 Python build error?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am using Python 3 on Sublime Text 3 (win8.1 64bit). When I write some code and then build, if there is an error, the Windows `PATH` is displayed as part of the error.

How do I remove the Windows `PATH` on Sublime Text 3 output when there is an error?

[image]

I wont to remove ==> I want to erase.

Comment: Thanks for comment:)

Comment: I've fixed up the question as much as I can, and I have a well-formulated answer to give. Let's reopen it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This behavior can be changed by commenting out four specific lines in `Packages/Default/exec.py`, which is the system file that runs build systems by default.

First, you'll need to install [**`PackageResourceViewer`**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) from Package Control. Next, open the Command Palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and type in ***`prv`*** to bring up the PackageResourceViewer options. Select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`, then `Default`, then `exec.py`. You can now hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to clear the Command Palette.

In the open file, scroll down to approximately line 212, looking specifically for this code block:

```
if "PATH" in merged_env:
    self.debug_text += "[path: " + str(merged_env["PATH"]) + "]"
else:
    self.debug_text += "[path: " + str(os.environ["PATH"]) + "]"
```

Select all 4 lines, then comment them out by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>. Finally, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to save the file.

This will create a new `Default` folder in your `Packages` directory (the one opened by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**) with `exec.py` inside, and will override the original file stored in `Default.sublime-package`, which is stored elsewhere, in Sublime's installation directory. If at any time you wish to have the full `PATH` printed again, simply open `Packages/Default/exec.py` and uncomment the lines you commented before, then save the file.

I would also recommend deleting `exec.py` and re-running through the procedure above *every time* you upgrade Sublime, as there may be vital changes to this file in the new release that are key for other parts of the build systems to work.

Comment: I admire your knowledge. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jimmy You're quite welcome, glad to help. It comes from many years using and studying the internals of Sublime :)

Comment: Since "shell_cmd" and "dir" are also displayed by default, you can comment these lines as well, to only display the error message.

Comment: @TawabG for that commenting line 279 & 346 would be enough `self.write(self.debug_text + "\n")`