# How to to remove file name from Sublime quick panel

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I feel the filename is unnecessary and it's distracting for me, I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611270/how-to-remove-the-windows-path-from-a-sublime-text-3-python-build-error) which requires something similar so I feel this should also be possible, I just don't know how.

[image]

The file name I want removing which I have highlighted and want to keep the full file path.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that, you have to make two things:

1. Make your project a sublime project, by creating a file called `.sublime-project` at your project's root.
2. Add the exclusion rules for the files you don't want to appear.

   ```
   {
     "folders":
       [

         {
           "path": "app/Http/Controllers/",
           "name": "controllers",
           "file_exclude_patterns": [Ccontroller.php"]
         }
       ]
   }
   ```

More about sublime projects [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html).

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the asked question. The desire is to change the display format in the panel to remove the file name but leave the path. Your answer will exclude the presentation of file information altogether which I do not believe is the desired behaviour.

Comment: I don't think it's going to exclude the path since I didn't use folder_exclude_patterns.